# Opening a file and outputting for function

Tags: c++

I have a code that I am doing and I got the basic version to work, I need help with how to implement a function in which the program reads a text file that I have saved and reads it and outputs it based on the function. Here is my code and what I have so far..

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <fstream>
 using namespace std;
 //start main
 int main()
{
double cost_merchandise, salary, yearly_rent, electricity_cost;
double totalCost, netProfit;
double PERCENTAGE_SALE = 0.15;
double PERCENTAGE_GOAL = 0.10;
double after_sale;
double Mark_up;

string line;
ifstream myfile ("F:/Intro To C++/ch0309.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
while ( getline (myfile,line) )
{
  cout << line << '\n';
}
myfile.close();
}

else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

return 0;

//gets data

cout << "Enter merchandise cost: ";
cin >> cost_merchandise;

cout << "Enter employee salary: ";
cin >> salary;

cout << "Enter yearly rent: ";
cin >> yearly_rent;

cout << "Enter the estimated electricity cost: ";
cin >> electricity_cost;
totalCost = cost_merchandise + salary + yearly_rent + electricity_cost;

//Output expenses, calculate mark ups, cost after 15%

cout << endl << setprecision(2) << fixed;
cout << "\nThe Company's expenses equals $: " << totalCost << endl << endl;
netProfit = cost_merchandise * PERCENTAGE_GOAL;
after_sale = netProfit + totalCost;
Mark_up = (after_sale - cost_merchandise) / 100;

cout << "A 10% profit is valued at $:  " << netProfit << endl;
cout << "Mark Up is " << Mark_up * 100 << "%" << endl;
return 0;
}
 //end of main
```

Comment: What's the goal here? This is something you could easily do in Excel, so I'm presuming there's a reason for doing it in C++.

Comment: I have the text file with the numbers I need, all I need is a way how to implement it. I tried looking online for different methods and they all ended in errors when I try to compile

Comment: This approach seems really confuse. You don't just put numbers in a file, usually it has some kind of format. INI, JSON, YAML, CSV, whatever it is, organize it.

Comment: How do I organize it?

Comment: In a *file format*. I listed four examples there. Pick one that you like.

Comment: Where's the link?,

Comment: All of that code seems irrelevant; I see nothing in it that even attempts to open a file and read it. You want to write code that reads numbers from a text file? Then *try,* and if you have trouble then show us your code and the text file.

Comment: Hold on, Give me a minute

Comment: UPDATE: I made an input function that worked, but it only displayed the numbers that were in the text file, I need some help in putting together a function that will do the calculations in the program based on the values in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, assuming that your data is splited by whitespaced or new lines :

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> getDataFromFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream file_input_stream(filename);
    if (!file_input_stream)
        throw std::exception("ifstream failed to open");

    std::vector<T> data;
    T input_data;
    while (!(file_input_stream >> input_data).eof()) {
        data.push_back(input_data);
    }

    return data;
}
```

and you use it like this :

```cpp
auto int_vector = getDataFromFile<int>(filename);
// You can modify the template parameter with the good data type ( char, double, string... )

//To output the vector :
for (const auto& i : int_vector) {
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: Thank You!, I will try to implement it

Comment: Where do I put it and do I have to put the name of the file in filename?

Comment: You need to put the function definition before the code calling it. And the filename parameter needs to be a valid path "pointing" to an existing filename. The path can be either a full path or a relative path, but in both cases, you will need to put somewhere in the filename string the name of the file. Example, if your file name is "example.txt" and your app runs in the same directory, the filename to open it will be "example.txt", or "./example.txt". You might maybe want to read a [fstream tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) for C++ I/O